# What is data- attribute used for in HTML? And, What are the common combinations with data attribute?

Tags: html

This is the part of the code I come across when i was viewing the source code of a website. A link where its proper description will also suffice. Somewhere i also saw data-info as attribute .

---

Here in span tag, data-msg is used:

```
<li>
    <span class="info" data-msg="sources.remittances.type" data-info="sources.remittances.info"></span>:
    <a data-msg="sources.remittances.name" target="_blank" href="http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTDEC/EXTDECPROSPECTS/0,,contentMDK:22759429~pagePK:64165401~piPK:64165026~theSitePK:476883,00.html"></a>
</li>
```

---

This is another example:

```
<section class="static">
    <div class="msg" data-msg="browser.not.supported"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

-W3c

[Webdesign Tuts gives a pretty good write-up of `data-`](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/).

It should be used when there aren't other elements or attributes that are designed to store specific data. It is not intended to be seen by the end user. But rather allow for a richer application.

The same link (above) gives a good example:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" data-duration="1min5secs" data-tempo="125bpm" data-artist="The Beatles" />
</audio>
```

You now have this data accessible to the application without needing to make an additional call to the server.

And for certain frameworks that allow for custom attributes (Looking at you Angular.js), prefixing all of the attributes with `data-` allows for code to validate, as I believe the browser ignores these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's an html attribute standard for storing arbitrary data that can be helpful to the UI/page functionality. It's meant to be a standard for representing data instead of just using arbitrary custom attributes

Answer (score 0):

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

[All You Need to Know About the HTML5 Data Attribute](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/)

[HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Answer (score -1):

A new feature being introduced in HTML 5 is the addition of custom data attributes. This is a, seemingly, bizarre addition to the specification – but actually provides a number of useful benefits.

visit

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/